# JavaScript :Multiple variables returned from a global function isn't able to be accessed by object

Tags: javascript, return, javascript-objects

I'm trying to have the location properties of my 'BB' object be set by my setLoc() function, but when I check the values in the debug console they come up as undefined. Other than that there are no errors being thrown in the console. Where have I gone wrong?

I've tried adding the function as a method to BB, but that brought additional errors.

Here's the two code blocks:

```
var loc = function setLoc(){
  let x;
  let y;
    if(random(1,2) == 1){
      x = random(-1000, 0);
      y = random(-1000, 0);
    }
      else{
        x = random(0, 1000);
        y = random(0, 1000);
      }
    return [x, y];
}

var bb = {
  done : false,
  hp : 10,
  fuel : 10,
  location : {
    x : loc[0],
    y : loc[1]
  },
}
```

Comment: You have to call your `loc()` function; you're just using the reference to the function itself.

Comment: You're never *calling* `loc`. You're just defining it, so `loc` refers to the function (and functions don't have `0` or `1` properties). If you meant to *call* it and put the result of calling it in `loc`, add `()` at the end after the closing `}`. (You should add the missing semicolon after them, too.)

Answer (score 1):

You define `loc` as a function. It should be a value - to do so, use an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) instead:

```js
var loc = (function setLoc() { ... })();
```

Comment: Glad to hear that! Oh by the way - this can be weird for new users, but *thank-you-comments* should be avoided. Instead, simply upvote or accept the answer. [more here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)